# append.html jquery is not working the same as the existing html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

i have a situation where im apending html to load more posts(pagination), and each post has a reply link, the appened html is not functioning properly:

the jquery post:

```
$(function () {
    //More Button
    $('.more').live("click", function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if (ID) {
            $("#more" + ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_more.php",
                data: "lastmsg=" + ID,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("ul.statuses").append(html);
                    $("#more" + ID).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');
        }

        return false;

    });
});
```

html file:

```
return <<<ENDOFRETURN
    <li>
        <a href="nano.com/$username"><img class="avatar" src="images/$picture" width="48" height="48" alt="avatar" /></a>
        <div class="tweetTxt">
            <strong><a href="nano.com/$username">$username</a></strong> $auto
            <div class="date">$rel</div>
            <a class ="reply" href="home.php?replyto=@$username&status_id=$id&reply_name=$username"> reply </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
ENDOFRETURN;
```

the reply link jquery:

```
function insertParamIntoField(anchor, param, field) {
    var query = anchor.search.substring(1, anchor.search.length).split('&');

    for (var i = 0, kv; i < query.length; i++) {
        kv = query[i].split('=', 2);
        if (kv[0] == param) {
            field.val(kv[1]);
            return;
        }
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("a.reply").click(function (e) {

        insertParamIntoField(this, "status_id", $("#status_id"));
        insertParamIntoField(this, "reply_name", $("#reply_name"));
        insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField"));

        $("#inputField").focus()
        $("#inputField").val($("#inputField").val() + ' ');

        e.preventDefault();
        return false; // prevent default action
    });
});
```

Comment: extra info: when i load more posts, and click the reply button, the page refershes!

Comment: You never define what "not working properly" means...

Comment: sorry, basically when i click reply on a link, its takes the username and inserts into the textbox, but when i load more posts using append.html, that reply link deosnt work! so i presume its something to do with appending the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a shot in the dark but it sounds like you haven't used a `.live()` event on the reply buttons. Any new buttons being appended to the document will not have the click event that you specified for them attached.

So in short make sure any buttons that are loaded dynamically and need to fire off an event are using a 'live' event binding.

Comment: thats what i have tried using the live() button aswell but that deosnt seem to work aswell!! im going to show you the code now!!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `click` handler to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this to make it work on links added later as well.:

```
$(function () {
  $("a.reply").live("click", function (e) {
     insertParamIntoField(this, "status_id", $("#status_id"));
     insertParamIntoField(this, "reply_name", $("#reply_name"));
     insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField"));
     $("#inputField").val(function(i, v) { return v + ' '; }).focus();
     return false;
  });
});
```